# what do you call it when an idea has so much potential it crosses over into social consciousness?

Tags: meaning

What do you call it when an idea has so much potential it crosses over into social consciousness?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Well, obviously, it's a meme.

Comment: A meme? (That is not its definition, but it matches pretty well, I think).

Comment: I don't understand what you meant my "crosses over into social consciousness". I completely agreed when I read pefhany's answer. But then someone wrote "viral", "meme". So, when a terrorizing sheikh declares "kill every American", and that declaration had so much potential and many teenagers in certain countries start fantasizing it. What is "crossing into social consciousness"? Is it made a deliberately loose and pliable phrase, so that you could garner as many types of answers as possible?

Comment: "Meme" seems to be wholly unrelated here?  A "meme" is just any catchy thing - it could be something utterly silly ("a video on youtube"), or it could be "a new slang word", or it could be "an invention", or it could be "an idea", and so on. The OP seems to be simply asking about "really revolutionary" inventions (or perhaps political philosophies), Spehro has given the answer

Comment: @JoeBlow: A meme is an academic term in social anthropology that means an idea that is so powerful that it pervades social conciousness - basically the definition of this question. The study of memes is called memetics. Memetics attempt to model ideas (memes) as organisms and society as an ecology that the memes live on. Memes have themselves become a meme in the form of the idea of "internet meme" - the catchy thing of the moment you mentioned.

Comment: (Dawkins coined the term "meme" in *Selfish Gene* - he also as you probably know gives a fascinating (very) long discussion of the subsequent popularity of the term, in appendices in his next two books - great stuff!)  A meme is "an element of a culture or system of behaviour passed from one individual to another by imitation or other non-genetic means."  The question is horribly written, and we'll probably never know as the OP disappeared, but I believe the OP just meant an "invention" that has "tremendous potential" - again the question is so poor I don't know why we're discussing it!  :O

Comment: The only word I haven't seen yet in the answers given is "zeitgeist". Look it up and see if that's what you're asking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just may be looking for spehro-pefhany's "paradigm shift." But your question is formed in a way that makes me wonder if you aren't looking for something more uncanny. An idea with "so much potential" (as you phrased it) means to me that it hasn't been actualized. In that case, you could be talking about a rather ephemeral social consciousness, such as "collective unconscious" (see Carl Jung's theories https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collective_unconscious). And without the ideation having some empirical grounding, the paradigm shift would not necessarily be a scientific one. And so the "crossing over" might be better explained by Jung's theory of "synchronicity" (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Synchronicity).

Comment: You have to vote up anything that mentions Jung and uses "ideation"  :)

Comment: It was synchronicity.

Answer (score 3):

The term that first comes to mind for this occurrence (popularized by Thomas Kuhn in [The Structure of Scientific Revolutions](http://projektintegracija.pravo.hr/_download/repository/Kuhn_Structure_of_Scientific_Revolutions.pdf)) is *[paradigm shift](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paradigm_shift)*.

> The
>   sorts of discoveries considered in the last section were not, at least
>   singly, responsible for such paradigm shifts as the Copernican,
>   Newtonian, chemical, and Einsteinian revolutions. Nor were they
>   responsible for the somewhat smaller, because more exclusively
>   professional, changes in paradigm produced by the wave theory of light,
>   the dynamical theory of heat, or Maxwell’s electromagnetic theory.